# Windows Phone - MediaElement not working anymore after navigation

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, mediaelement, isolatedstoragefile

I have a problem with the MediaElement in my windows phone (8) application. It's working fine until I navigate to some other page and come back on the page containing the MediaElement.

I have the following code to play a stream coming from Bing Translator APIs:

```
private void TranslationService_SpeakComplete(object sender, SpeakCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = e.Stream;

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                MediaElement.Stop();
                MediaElement.Source = null;

                string filename = "FlipNLearnItAudio";
                using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    bool fileExists = isf.FileExists(filename);

                    if (fileExists)
                    {
                        isf.DeleteFile(filename);
                    }

                    var isfs = isf.CreateFile(filename);
                    using (isfs)
                    {
                        Helpers.SaveFile(stream, isfs);
                        isfs.Position = 0;

                        MediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
                        MediaElement.SetSource(isfs);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: log exception
            }
        });
    }
```

The biggest problem is that there's no exception.... the "MediaElement.SetSource(isfs);" is called normally without any exception!

Do you have any idea of what can happen?

Thanks for any help!
Bastien

Comment: I have the same problem has anyone found a reason, or better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a solution to my problem. I put the MediaElement in the App.xaml resources and now it's working fine...

But it doesn't explain why it was not working with the MediaElement in the MainPage.xaml.

If somebody has the answer, I would be very interested to hear it ;-).